# Windows Server 2008 - Windows Server Backup - Email Alerts

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, batch-file, windows-server-backup

I would like to create a script that emails me when a scheduled daily backup runs. I'd prefer the email to indicate success or failure. I understand that this is not an easy thing to do with Windows Server 2008.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way would be to setup an alert from the eventlog for backup events.

Otherwise roll your own PowerShell script to control the backup and alerting (WSB comes with a number of cmdlets for PowerShell)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on setting up an alert from the eventlog? Thanks!

Comment: check out http://www.petri.co.il/assigning-custom-tasks-to-events.htm

Comment: can you make me an example of how to check successful backup with cmdlets of powrshell ? thanks